# javascript getImageData cannot get pixel value

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Canvas</title>

    <script>
        window.onload = function () {
            var preview = document.getElementById('preview');
            var r = document.getElementById('r');
            var g = document.getElementById('g');
            var b = document.getElementById('b');
            var a = document.getElementById('a');

            var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');

            var building = new Image();
            building.src = "img/cinema.png";

            building.onload = function(){
                var c = canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(building, 0, 0, 256, 200, 0, 0, 256, 200);

                var img = c.getImageData(150, 160, 1, 1);

                var idata = img.data;

                var red = idata[0];
                var green = idata[1];
                var blue = idata[2];
                var alpha = idata[3];

                r.innerHTML = red;
                g.innerHTML = green;
                b.innerHTML = blue;
                a.innerHTML = (alpha > 0) ? alpha : 'Transparent';
            }
        }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

        ul li { font-weight: bold; }
        ul li span { font-weight: normal; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300">

</canvas>
<ul>
    <li><div id="preview"></div></li>
    <li>Red: <span id="r">NULL</span></li>
    <li>Green: <span id="g">NULL</span></li>
    <li>Blue: <span id="b">NULL</span></li>
    <li>Alpha: <span id="a">NULL</span></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

I just want to test the getImageData function.

The image can be shown up on chrome but the value of `iData[]` is all NULL.

The png i used is 256*200 pixel. Would anyone can give me some hints why the
above script cannot work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nah, that wont work - I'd be surprised if you didn't find that `c` holds a different value than you think.

You appear to be treating `c` as though it is the result of `canvas.getContext('2d')` - yet if you look at your code, `c` holds the result of the call to `drawImage(building, 0, 0, 256, 200, 0, 0, 256, 200);`

So, what does this mean? You've grabbed the context correctly (into a temporary variable), then used it to draw an image. The result of this drawing operation is what you've stored into `c`.

Make the following change:

```
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
c.drawImage(building, 0, 0, 256, 200, 0, 0, 256, 200);

var img = c.getImageData(150, 160, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have changed the code as your suggest but the pixel values are still NULL.

Comment: If i not draw the png file and simply call fillStyle = "rgb(0,0,0)" and fillRect(0,0,300,300), the pixel value array can show 0,0,0,255.

Comment: @user2975639 - You're welcome. Uh-huh, that's correct. The canvas holds 32bit pixel data. Each pixel has a red,green,blue and alpha value. When you use `rgb(0,0,0)` you're only supplying 24 of those 32 bits. The browser then sets the alpha value to 255. So, it still has a colour value - a value that corresponds to black in your example. Try to draw a gradient using your image editor of choice (e.g The Gimp or Photoshop). Running it from 255,0,0,0 to 0,0,0,255 - you'll get a different result than if you do 255,0,0,0 to 255,255,255,255...

Comment: Thank you. But i sill don't know why cannot get the png(32bit) pixel. >_<~~

Comment: Ahh, I think I've just realized what the problem may be. How are you opening this html file? Are you opening it from a local (absolute) location or via a webserver? The first would look like `file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/enhzflep/canvasQuestion.html`  while the second would be `http://localhost/enhzflep/canvasQuestion.html` - if you open the javascript console, you may see a message that says `Unable to get image data from canvas because the canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.`

Comment: I have open as local. A folder contain the html file and a img folder which cantain the cinema.png file. I just double click the html and chrome will show the picture and the link is "file:///C:/Users/A/Desktop/webgame/try.html"

Comment: That's your problem then. I forget the terminology for it, but basically it's a security policy. It prevents a hosted page from finding out information about a client computer when the page is viewed. You'll have to view the page via a webserver(i.e with a `http://localhost` type address), Xampp or Wamp will do the trick. Took me a day or two to realize where I was going wrong when I first tried to follow canvas tutorials. Truly maddening, it was! :) - I could draw to the canvas and get that data back, but could NOT get the pixel data of a loaded image file.

Comment: WOW, thank you so much!!!!!!!!!! It works \@@/ If you don't answer my question, i really don't know when can solve this problem!!!! thank you